# s3slider adding navigation

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

Using s3slider as a plugin for Wordpress and it's pretty good, but client wants a navigation in so they can see how many slides there are and easily navigate through them...

Has anybody buily this in before, if so would you be able to provide the code?

If not I'll start digging in.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up swapping out the control for:

Nivo slider for wordpress

It had arrows on so that did the trick... for

Answer (score 0):

I found s3slider (and I can say ALL sliders) replaceable by [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

It's easy... perfect for multiple instances on page ... and supports navigation natively !

Also it will provide extensibility when you need it !

Comment: Unfortunatley the WP Jquery cycle, doesn't allow users to type text that appears in an opacity div... Unlike s3slider